# Facebook sharing won't pull any images anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, addthis

I have created a company blog and have begun implementing various social sharing plugins, had a look at integrating with OG and now Facebook won't pull any images when the page is shared.

The debugger tool says that it can find a suitable image (the featured image for each post) and when I share the same link to LinkedIn the images pull fine.

I can't work out for the life of me what might be wrong, again it's not that Facebook isn't pulling the right image, it's not pulling ANY.

Does anyone have experience with this/know what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your company blog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your og:url value to http://www.chapman-freeborn.com/en/blog/ ( add the trailing / )

Also fill your og:image value so facebook will get that image...

Handy tool for debug : http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.chapman-freeborn.com%2Fen%2Fblog%2F

Docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Cheers!

Comment: I have added og meta tags to my header: 
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Chapman Freeborn Blog"/>