# Facebook sharing won't pull through ANY images anymore

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, sharing, meta

I have created a company blog and have begun implementing various social sharing plugins, had a look at integrating with OG and now Facebook won't pull any images when the page is shared.

The debugger tool says that it can find a suitable image (the featured image for each post) and when I share the same link to LinkedIn the images pull fine.

I can't work out for the life of me what might be wrong, again it's not that Facebook isn't pulling the right image... it's not pulling ANY.

Does anyone have experience with this/know what might be wrong?

www.chapman-freeborn.com/en/blog

(see duplicate post on stackoverflow [Facebook sharing won't pull any images anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609149/facebook-sharing-wont-pull-through-any-images-anymore) )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook sharing won't pull through ANY images anymore,](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11609149/facebook-sharing-wont-pull-through-any-images-anymore)

Answer (score 0):

If you run your blog through the [OG Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.chapman-freeborn.com/en/blog/) you will see that your page has errors that need to be fixed. This is the reason why images aren't coming through...